# Reading an Avro Record which was written with a different writer schema

Tags: java, avro

Let's say I'm deserializing a GenericRecord which was written with an Encoder (not a FileWriter, so the schema's not stored with the serialized Record). And I'm using a reader schema which is a superset of the writer schema (i.e., the reader schema contains all the fields of the writer schema, plus a few more).

When I attempt to read the Record, do I need to know what the writer schema was? Specifically, do I need to provide both the writer schema *and* the reader schema when I instantiate my GenericDatumReader?

Or can I create a GenericDatumReader, specifying only the reader schema, and have the reader deserialize whatever fields it finds in the encoded Record and provide defaults for the rest of the fields (as specified by the reader schema)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible unless you know the schema that the writer used. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193729/avro-how-can-i-use-default-fields-when-i-dont-know-the-exact-schema-that-the