# Avro: How can I use default fields when I don't know the exact schema that the "writer" used

Tags: java, json, avro

In Java Avro, how do I parse *data1*, *data2* and *data3* below to a *GenericRecord*.

```
//Schema
{
    "type": "record", "name": "user",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "colour", "type": "string", "default": "green"},
        {"name": "mass", "type": "int", "default": 100}
    ]
}
//data 1
{"name":"Sean"}
//data 2
{"name":"Sean", "colour":"red"}
//data 3
{"name":"Sean", "colour":"red", "mass":200}
```

I've seen some discussion on schema evolution etc, and the ability pass a *writer's schema* and a *reader's schema* to GenericDatumReader and ResolvingDecoder, but I only have one schema. In general I don't know what exact schema the writer used (if any).

I could "infer" a "base" schema by parsing the schema and removing all fields with default values. However, if there are multiple fields with default values some may/may not be present so I will not be able to infer the schema that would be compliant with the data.

For example

- If I try *GenericDatumReader* using the given schema to read *data3*
  then parsing is successful.
- If I try *GenericDatumReader* using the inferred schema to read *data1*
  then parsing is successful.
- If I try *GenericDatumReader* with a *ResolvingDecoder* using both the inferred schema and the given schema to read *data1* then parsing is successful.
- All other options fail to parse *data1* and *data3* into *GenericRecord*s containing all values the JSON string and appropriate defaults for missing fields.
- ***And it doesn't seem to be possible to correctly parse data2 at all!***

Has anyone any advice?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder;

public class DefaultAvroTest2 {

    private static String properSchama_string = "{" +
            "        \"type\": \"record\"," +
            "        \"name\": \"user\"," +
            "        \"fields\": [" +
            "            {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}," +
            "            {\"name\": \"colour\", \"type\": \"string\", \"default\": \"green\"}," +
            "            {\"name\": \"mass\", \"type\": \"int\", \"default\": 100}" +
            "        ]" +
            "       }";

    private static String inferred_base_schama_string = "{" +
            "        \"type\": \"record\"," +
            "        \"name\": \"user\"," +
            "        \"fields\": [" +
            "            {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}" +
            "        ]" +
            "       }";


    private static String data1 = "{\"name\":\"Sean\"}";
    private static String data2 = "{\"name\":\"Sean\", \"colour\":\"red\"}";
    private static String data3 = "{\"name\":\"Sean\", \"colour\":\"blue\", \"mass\":200}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        System.out.println("\nObject 1 :\n"+data1);
        System.out.println("\nObject 2 :\n"+data2);
        System.out.println("\nObject 3 :\n"+data3);

        Schema inferred_base_schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(inferred_base_schama_string);
        Schema defined_schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(properSchama_string);

        System.out.println("\nProper schema :\n"+defined_schema.toString(true));
        System.out.println("\nA base schema that could be inferred from the proper schema :\n"+inferred_base_schema.toString(true));

        JsonDecoder jsonDecoder_inferred_1 = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(inferred_base_schema, data1);
        JsonDecoder jsonDecoder_inferred_2 = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(inferred_base_schema, data2);
        JsonDecoder jsonDecoder_inferred_3 = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(inferred_base_schema, data3);

            //Correct
        GenericRecord object1_inferred = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(inferred_base_schema).read(null, jsonDecoder_inferred_1);
            //Incorrect: colour is missing
        GenericRecord object2_inferred = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(inferred_base_schema).read(null, jsonDecoder_inferred_2);
            //Incorrect: colour and mass are missing
        GenericRecord object3_inferred = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(inferred_base_schema).read(null, jsonDecoder_inferred_3);


        ResolvingDecoder resolvingDecoder1 = DecoderFactory.get().resolvingDecoder(inferred_base_schema, defined_schema, DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(defined_schema, data1));
        ResolvingDecoder resolvingDecoder2 = DecoderFactory.get().resolvingDecoder(inferred_base_schema, defined_schema, DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(defined_schema, data2));
        ResolvingDecoder resolvingDecoder3 = DecoderFactory.get().resolvingDecoder(inferred_base_schema, defined_schema, DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(defined_schema, data3));

            //Correct
        GenericRecord object1_resolved = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(defined_schema).read(null, resolvingDecoder1);
            //Incorrect: colour is default(green) not red
        GenericRecord object2_resolved = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(defined_schema).read(null, resolvingDecoder2);
            //Incorrect: colour is default(green) not blue, and mass is default(100) not 200
        GenericRecord object3_resovled = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(defined_schema).read(null, resolvingDecoder3);

        JsonDecoder jsonDecoder_defined_1 = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(defined_schema, data1);
        JsonDecoder jsonDecoder_defined_2 = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(defined_schema, data2);
        JsonDecoder jsonDecoder_defined_3 = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(defined_schema, data3);

            //Fail: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected string. Got END_OBJECT
        //GenericRecord object1_defined = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(defined_schema).read(null, jsonDecoder_defined_1);
            //Fail: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected int. Got END_OBJECT
        //GenericRecord object2_defined = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(defined_schema).read(null, jsonDecoder_defined_2);
            //Correct
        GenericRecord object3_defined = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(defined_schema).read(null, jsonDecoder_defined_3);


            //Correct
        System.out.println("\nObject 1 read with inferred schema:\n"+object1_inferred);
            //Incorrect: colour is missing
        System.out.println("\nObject 2 read with inferred schema:\n"+object2_inferred);
            //Incorrect: colour and mass are missing
        System.out.println("\nObject 3 read with inferred schema:\n"+object3_inferred);
            //Correct
        System.out.println("\nObject 1 read with resolving decoder:\n"+object1_resolved);
            //Incorrect: colour is default(green) not red
        System.out.println("\nObject 2 read with resolving decoder:\n"+object2_resolved);
            //Incorrect: colour is default(green) not blue, and mass is default(100) not 200
        System.out.println("\nObject 3 read with resolving decoder:\n"+object3_resovled);
            //Fail
        //System.out.println("\nObject 1 read with defined schema:\n"+object1_defined);
            //Fail
        //System.out.println("\nObject 2 read with defined schema:\n"+object2_defined);
            //Correct
        System.out.println("\nObject 3 read with defined schema:\n"+object3_defined);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Object 1 :
{"name":"Sean"}

Object 2 :
{"name":"Sean", "colour":"red"}

Object 3 :
{"name":"Sean", "colour":"blue", "mass":200}

Proper schema :
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "user",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "name",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "colour",
    "type" : "string",
    "default" : "green"
  }, {
    "name" : "mass",
    "type" : "int",
    "default" : 100
  } ]
}

A base schema that could be inferred from the proper schema :
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "user",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "name",
    "type" : "string"
  } ]
}

Object 1 read with inferred schema:
{"name": "Sean"}

Object 2 read with inferred schema:
{"name": "Sean"}

Object 3 read with inferred schema:
{"name": "Sean"}

Object 1 read with resolving decoder:
{"name": "Sean", "colour": "green", "mass": 100}

Object 2 read with resolving decoder:
{"name": "Sean", "colour": "green", "mass": 100}

Object 3 read with resolving decoder:
{"name": "Sean", "colour": "green", "mass": 100}

Object 3 read with defined schema:
{"name": "Sean", "colour": "blue", "mass": 200}
```